# Find starting and Ending positions for every selected word Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to find the starting and ending position of selected text in javascript. for Example:

str = "The learned Judge of Family Court at Indore, Madhya Pradesh is directed to transmit the case records of the aforesaid case to the Family Court at Bandra, Mumbai, Maharashtra within a period of one month from the date of supply of a copy of this order to him."

if I select **Family** after ", judge of" then what will be starting and ending position of it and if I select  **Family** after "to the" then what will be its starting and ending positions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not the place to ask for a tutorial, nor the place to find free programmers**. Your question should _show_ that you've put some efford into solving your own problem and should be answerable without writing half a book.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

To get a Range object that you can get the start and end index points from

Comment: ok Thankyou this gives me text i want its starting index and ending index integer values.

Comment: Okay I got it positions but i have to match those positions within database so that get exact string how to do that?